# Robolectric does not support API level 28

Tags: android, robolectric

Although this question has been answered for previous versions in other threads, none of the answers seems to work for me with api 28 right now so..

All Robolectric tests worked fine when on api 27. Now when my app api target is 28 they all fail.

I have

`@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class, sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.P])`

on my test class.

Diving into Robolectrics internal SdkConfig.java it *looks* like they add support for api 28:

`addSdk(Build.VERSION_CODES.P, "P", "4651975", "P");`

But when evaluating that line of code in the debugger, `Build.VERSION_CODES.P` evaluates to `10000`. Not sure what's going on there.

I'm running Robolectric 3.8, and also tried with the 4.0 alpha version with no luck.

What am I missing?

**Edit:** For now I'm just running on the latest (what I can tell) supported api version, by annotating the test class(es) with `@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])`. This will give you Android 8.1.0 (api 27).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Second edit:** This has graduated from snapshot and is now available with

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-beta-1'
```

i.e. you no longer need the maven snapshot line.

---

**Edit:** This is now fixed and available in the snapshot build. In your gradle build file (app level) add

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

---

Now that this [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3935#issuecomment-398449409) is updated with info from a contributor it seems like there will be a new 4.0 alpha release that [fixes](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/pull/3933) the issue within this week.

Answer (score 17):

To complete Algar's answer, you can bypass temporarily this error (meanwhile Robolectric fix this [issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3935#issuecomment-398449409)) by annotating your test class like that :

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1])
class YourUnitTests {

...

}
```

It will force Robolectric using Android API 27.