# Problem with running the first test on the Robolectric

Tags: java, android, robolectric

Strange behavior. I'm just setting up the `Robolectric` now.

Here are my settings:

**build.app**

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.0-alpha-3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

and

```
testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
```

**build.project**

```
repositories {
     maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
}
```

So that is my **activity**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

public class RootActivityTest {
private RootActivity activity;

@Before
public void setup()  {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(RootActivity.class)
            .create()
            .resume()
            .get();
}

@Test
public void checkActivityNotNull() throws Exception {
    assertNotNull(activity);
}
}
```

And now when I run a test with this configuration, I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: MultiDex installation failed (/tmp/robolectric-Method_checkActivityNotNull6294215780013113020/com.mandarine.android-sourceDir (Is a directory)).

Tried to implement one of this library:

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:multidex:3.4.2"
```

or

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0"
```

But doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you implement two versions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870425/robolectric-does-not-support-api-level-28

Comment: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3935

Comment: @TheWanderer Updated question, check please.

Comment: @NileshRathod thx for links, I go by the script, but new questions arise since I still can't run a simple test. So updated the question but your links will be helpful in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps someone will be useful. Also u can start from this [link](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/#building-with-gradle)

My experience how to run tests with Robolectric:

**build.grade**:

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'

testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

Here is my **MainActivity**:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = 21)

public class MainActivityTest {

@Test
public void shouldNotBeNull() throws Exception {
    MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    assertNotNull(activity);
}
}
```

And last trick, add in **gradle.properties**:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Works on our side without disabling aapt2

Comment: With the same setup and these libraries?
it would be great to get rid of this addiction - `aapt2`

Comment: I think so. We don't use multidex from robolectric but it doesn't change much with aapt2